# ruby mysql asynchronous on windows

Tags: mysql, ruby, windows, asynchronous

mysql2 gem have "Not supported on Windows" note.
I need a simple solution to do async calls to mysql database on windows. No need for ORM support.
Preferably not with Eventmachine as I'd rather not have my whole app packed inside EM.run block.

Comment: I am not sure if there are any another reactors.

Comment: No reactor is needed. Only call #=> nil, and result retrieval in future time.

Answer (score 0):

There is this, but doesn't seem to have been any changes in the past 2 years.
Perhaps it will give you what you need and I'm sure you can contact the author.

https://github.com/chrismoos/async-mysql

Comment: this uses Eventmachine so it's not really what I'm looking for. And even if, I'd rather use em-synchrony

Comment: How about this? I don't see any trace of EventMachine Or ORM....github.com/oldmoe/mysqlplus (Suspect it may not support Windows). Why not write it yourself based on the code from mysqlplus?

Comment: both c_async_query and async_query from mysqlplus run the query in a blocking fashion for some reason

Comment: Seemingly you not going to find anything outside of writing something yourself :( Wish I had better news.But take a look at this implementation, which is the basis for MysqlPlus (https://github.com/oldmoe/mysqlplus/blob/master/ext/mysql.c)